# print regex output with a name defined to it

Tags: python-3.x

I have a 3 regex patterns, which matches and give me the output. However, I am trying to divide the output and assign a name for each.

```
text = "i am trying to match expr1 in a, expr2 in b and expr3 in c"
var = ["a", "b", "c"]
compile_text = [regex for a, regex for b, regex for c]
for patrn in compile_text:
   regex = patrn.search(text)
   if regex is not None:
   for i in var:
      print(i, ":", regex.group())
```

Currently, my output is like this:

```
   a:expr1
   b:expr1
   c:expr1
   a:expr2
   b:expr2
   c:expr2
   a:expr3
   b:expr3
   b:expr3
```

Not sure how to assign regex.group() output to var.
Is it possible to get the final result as:

```
   a = expr1
   b = expr2
   c = expr3
```

Comment: i tried assigning the regex to a list. It did not work

Comment: Please add a more realistic example (with `text`) and format your code.

Comment: Your current code example doesn't work; it results in a syntax error.